# Segmentation fault using .init_array section

Tags: c, elf

I'm learning **ELF** a bit and ran into a strange seg fault

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

__attribute__((constructor(102))) static void init1() {
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

__attribute__((constructor(101))) static void init2() {
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void another_init1() {
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void another_init2() {
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

typedef void (*init)();
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) init init_arr[2] = {another_init1, another_init2};

static void my_function_1() {}

int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

compiling this with `gcc -o hello hello.c` and running `./hello` I see

```
[root@20f890034489 ch5]# ./hello 
init2
init1
Segmentation fault
```

this is coming from the *.init_arr*. If I make this array contain a single function ptr, everything works as expected, but with 2 ptrs in there, it seg faults.

Any suggestion? Just find this strange

VK

Comment: This looks on purpose. If the array has more then one element, gcc inserts NULL when concatenating sections, see [this source](https://onlinegdb.com/SJIc2nmZr). This makes __libc_csu_init jump to NULL.

Comment: regarding NULL it's clear, but you do not insert that into `.init/fini\_array`. the answer regarding alignment was correct 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `init_array` should be aligned to size of a pointer; if you change that to:

```
__attribute__((section(".init_array"), aligned(sizeof (void*)))) init init_arr[2] = {another_init1, another_init2};
```

it will work.

If not (at least on x86-64) `gcc` will align your array to a 16 bytes boundary, creating a 8 bytes gap in the `.init_array` section between the 3 function pointers already there (`frame_dummy` + your `init1` and `init2`) and the 2 new functions, which will appear to the dynamic linker as a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Och, wow, [it works](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy9ap2XWr). With current C you rather should `aligned(_Alignof(void*))`.